# Adding images to a table view on left side

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have created a  table cell and i wish to add image on left side .Image is to be given for all cells i have created.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    }

     if([indexPath row] == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text=@"mano";
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }
    if([indexPath row] == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text=@"happy";
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    if([indexPath row] == 2){
        cell.textLabel.text=@"welcome";
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    }
     if([indexPath row] == 3)
     {
         cell.textLabel.text=@"enjoy";
         cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];
     }
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Dear, In first line u have mentioned that u have created custom class for cell and how it works with UITableViewCell class, you have to define cell object of Custom class.

Comment: no i hav created tableview only..

Comment: As you have mentioned in first line, i gave ans as per custom cell. It's ok, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
```

and then

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.photos objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex] ofType:nil];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file]
```

In place of **[UiImage imageNamed:@""]** use **[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]**.

Because ImageNamed takes too much memory (Check this link :- http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2012/04/19/ios-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile/).

Hope this will help u.

Answer (score 3):

Put in cellforrowatindexpath.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

used this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
}



if([indexPath row] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text=@"mano";
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow0.png"];

}
if([indexPath row] == 1){
    cell.textLabel.text=@"happy";
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow1.png"];

}
if([indexPath row] == 2){
    cell.textLabel.text=@"welcome";
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow2.png"];

}
 if([indexPath row] == 3)
 {
     cell.textLabel.text=@"enjoy";
     cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow3.png"];
 }
    return cell;
}
```

imageView is a outlet of UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

first of all to display an image in tableview there is no need to use custom cell. First make your tableviewcell to basic. Assign tableviewcell reuse identifier. Write this code for tableviewcell

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

     if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    }

             cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
             cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];

            return cell;

}

If you have used storyboard then no need to check if cell is nil. It intializes cell automatically when dequeing is not possible. Please check this tutorial.
```

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1